# Dart: Share common methods among mixins

Tags: dart, mixins

Is there any way to put a mixin on another mixin like this? I want to share some common methods among a few mixins.

```
mixin CircleMixin with SquareMixin {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible to compose mixins. See [this issue that's tracking the request](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/540) for this feature.